# Put a command in history without executing it

Tags: zsh

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), if I have a command on the line, and I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd> (with the cursor anywhere on the line), it adds a `#` to the front of the line, commenting it out, 'executes' it (which does nothing since it's now commented out), and puts it into the history. It's really useful for when I type some or all of a command and realise I need to run another command first and come back to that one later.

How can I do the same operation in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)? The commenting-out isn't important: all I care about is that the command doesn't happen right now, but can be retrieved from history later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three options:

- zsh has the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> by default that pushes the current line.

  Use it like this:

  1. Type *command*.
  2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.
  3. Execute *othercommand*.
  4. *command* will reappear.

  Technically, this doesn't put it in the history. Also, if you need to execute another command before *command*, you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> again.
- Also by default, the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> cut and yank (paste) the current line.

  Use them like this:

  1. Type *command*.
  2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.
  3. Execute *othercommand*.
  4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.
  5. *command* will reappear.

  This would work in bash as well and it uses its own clipboard, i.e., they contents of the clipboard managed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>Shift</kbd> +) <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd> and *select* / *middle-click* will remain unaltered.
- Last but not least, you can permanently enable comments on the command-line by executing

  ```
  echo setopt interactivecomments >> ~/.zshrc
  ```

  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> doesn't work here, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> / <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> achieves the same result.

To see all available keyboard shortcuts, execute

```
bindkey
```

Answer (score 10):

Option four (as an answer to the title of the question, not its explanation ;-):

- `print -S "this line goes to the history"`

Excerpt from `zshbuiltins(1)`: "`print -S` Place  the  results in the history list instead of on the standard output.  In this case only a single argument is
                     allowed; it will be split into words as if it were a full shell command line.  The effect is  similar  to  reading
                     the line from a history file with the HIST_LEX_WORDS option active."

Answer (score 5):

A widgetification of @mpy's answer, add this to your .zshrc

```
to-history() { print -S $BUFFER ; BUFFER= }
zle -N to-history
bindkey 'œ' to-history
```

Note: œ is what I get on a Mac for alt/option-q, adjust for your terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vi mode, then press `ESC` to enter normal mode, and then `Shift+3` (`#`). This will put the commented out command in history.